# Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c

On this line of code:

```
[self.a8.text intValue]=[self.a7.text intValue]+[self.a6.text intValue];
```

I am getting this compiler error:

> Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

Why is that happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to the return of intValue.  Try

```
self.a8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.a7.text intValue]+[self.a6.text intValue]];
```

This assume that self.a8.text is assignable